# Why does Seq2SeqTrainer produces error during evaluation when using T5?

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, huggingface, huggingface-trainer

Following the tutorial [here](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/en/tasks/summarization). I've tried to adapt it to my dataset.

But, I've noticed that during evaluation the `Seq2SeqTrainer` calls the `compute_metrics` `3` times.

The first time it passes the correct validation/test set, but the other `2` times I don't know what the hell is passing on or why is calling the `compute_metrics` `3` times?

Notice in the screenshot below the validation set has 6400 samples, which is correctly passed to the `compute_metrics` the first time it is being called by the `Seq2SeqTrainer`, but what are the other `2` calls passing the second time `predictions` and `labels` of size `127` and third time it calls the `compute_metrics` it passes some type of scalar values for both the `predictions` and `labels`.

Could anyone explain what the hell is going on here?

Why does the `Seq2SeqTrainer` calls the `compute_metrics` 3 times when it should only call it once passing the actual predictions and labels on validation set which is of size `6400` samples?

```
training_args = Seq2SeqTrainingArguments(
    output_dir="t5_checkpoints",
    learning_rate=2e-5,
    per_device_train_batch_size=640,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=640,
    num_train_epochs=10,
    weight_decay=0.01,
    evaluation_strategy="epoch",
    save_strategy="epoch",
    save_total_limit=3,
    predict_with_generate=True,
    generation_max_length=128,
    generation_num_beams=4,
    load_best_model_at_end=True,
    logging_steps=1,
)
```

```
trainer = Seq2SeqTrainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=tokenized_data["train"],
    eval_dataset=tokenized_data["valid"],
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    data_collator=data_collator,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share your `training_args` and `trainer` definitions?

Comment: I've edited the question to reflect the `training_args` and `trainer` definitions accordingly.

Comment: The evaluation strategy is set to "epoch" so the `compute_metrics` should run after every epoch, in this case 10 times. Where are the logs printing `preds.shape...` from? Did it complete all 10 epochs?

Comment: No, what you're saying is not correct. Read my question carefully and observe the tqdm progress bar from the screenshot. The `preds.shape` comes from me putting a print statement inside `compute_metrics`. So, after 1 epoch of training is completed then the eval should follow, which indeed happens, but for some reason the `trainer` calls the `compute_metrics` 3 times that's why my `preds.shape` statements are printing 3 times. The 1st time is the correct passing the valid set but dunno what are the other 2 or why/what is being passed from `trainer` to `compute_metrics`

Comment: You'll need to share both the `compute_metrics` function and how you are calling `trainer.train()`. Also that is how `compute_metrics` behaves, it is run after *every* epoch under this strategy, it is not immediately obvious that your issue here occurs immediately at the end of only 1 epoch.

Comment: Try to give the details that @fam-woodpecker requested and that'll help us help you. Also don't post the screenshot of the error, copy and paste the whole traceback and we can better help you.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the issue was a hidden state in the jupyter notebook which was recursively calling `compute_metrics` passing as arguments parts of `preds, labels` until there was nothing left but a scalar value. Now things "seem to work" (i.e., no errors but seems like the model is not learning when tested even though the task is simple. Train accuracy reaches 90% but upon evaluation the model produces wrong text summaries compared to the true labels.)